# Visual Studio - Auto Hide/Show Toolbox in Code/Designer modes

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I know I can manually pin and unpin the Visual Studio Toolbox, but what I would like to do is have it pinned when viewing the designer and automatically hide when I view the code. Is this possible?

Thanks, Jamie

Comment: I've always wanted this too... the toolbox is a waste of space in code view (you can put code snippets in it, and maybe other stuff,  but who cares?).

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I know; I don't think the toolbox can differentiate between code and design views.

It's possible you could write an extension with the Visual Studio SDK that does what you're asking but I don't think it is possible otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Perspectives](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d446d9d3-4994-4d78-853d-f266b0bfd4ec) extension can help you. After installing you can save your current layout as perspective (just like in Eclipse) in Visual Studio 2010 and then switch between them.