# Can I have a panel like Toolbox only visible when in Design mode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

On my laptop I try to maximize workspace within Visual Studio. If I'm just dealing with code, I keep all of my panels on the left and right hidden via auto-hide.

However, if I'm working in Design mode I pin the toolbox, properties, etc so they're always visible. I was hoping to find a way to actually hide the panels when I tab to a file only dealing with text (not in Design mode), and regain the panel when I return to a tab in Design mode, **no manual pinning/unpinning required**. I'm not fond of just mousing over the panel tab so it pops into view. I like to keep them permanently there while in Design mode.

Going from https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYmHu.png to https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQLGP.png is basically what I'm referring to.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035913/visual-studio-auto-hide-show-toolbox-in-code-designer-modes/8035947#8035947

Comment: It is completely a duplicate, actually. My searching failed me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if there's a better way but I was able to create a macro to do this. Open Macro IDE in Tools -> Macros -> Macros IDE. Open EnvironmentEvents under MyMacros. Add the following code:

```
Private Sub WindowEvents_WindowActivated(ByVal GotFocus As EnvDTE.Window, ByVal LostFocus As EnvDTE.Window) Handles WindowEvents.WindowActivated

    If GotFocus.Caption.EndsWith(" [Design]") Then
        DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindProperties).AutoHides = False
    Else
        DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindProperties).AutoHides = True
    End If

End Sub
```

If the properties panel is not already opened, you add this code to open:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.PropertiesWindow")
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with VS 2013 or later? I know the macro capability was removed so I have to download an extension, but none of the ones I found seem to have the capability to add environment event macros.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Perspectives](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d446d9d3-4994-4d78-853d-f266b0bfd4ec) extension. After installing you can save your current layout as perspective (just like in Eclipse) in Visual Studio 2010 and then switch between them. The only bad thing is what you can't switch between them automatically. I don't know maybe we can modify sources of extension(if it's available).

Comment: I really like that. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's nice.

Comment: I agree with you. Also try "Layout O Rama" http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35966ad9-430f-4ad7-9186-4394b784e36c